# Mapping interface using FluentNhibernate and Autofac

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, mapping, fluent-nhibernate

i'm have a hard and extreming question, how i'm may using FluentNHibernate for mapping a interface? follow a example below how i'm imagine do:
I'm have a interface:

```
public interface IUser
{
    String Name { get; set; }
    City City { get; set; }
}
```

and i'm have a class with implement this interface:

```
public class User : IUser
{
    String Name { get; set; }
    ICity City { get; set; }
}
```

Consider witch too exist a class for City and contains a property named Country and too exists at its interface...
I need to use FluentNHibernate to do the mapping as follows:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<IUser>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
       Map(e => e.Name);
       References<City>(x => x.City).Cascade.All();
    }
}
public class CityMap: ClassMap<ICity>
{
    public CityMap()
    {
        Map(e => e.Country);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mapping interfaces is [supported](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-class):

> It is perfectly acceptable for the named persistent class to be an interface. You would then declare implementing classes of that interface using the `<subclass>` element.

The `<subclass>` element's equivalent in Fluent NHibernate is `SubclassMap<T>`, I suppose. Therefore, although it's not clear what your actual problem is, can you try this instead:

```
public class UserMap : SubclassMap<IUser>
{
}

public class CityMap: SubclassMap<ICity>
{
}
```